# Automatically input username and password for OAuth

Tags: python, oauth, jawbone, two-legged

I am running a research project where we create the participant's Jawbone accounts. I am writing a piece of program that captures all of the participants' step counts. I am wondering how I can feed the username and password without having this page below pop up.

In essence, I want to streamline the process so that I can get the oauth access token without any user manual input. I am writing all of this in Python (Google App Engine).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid that page is to have already stored the OAuth tokens for the user. As part of the OAuth protocol, each user has to grant your application access to the data.

How are you planning to gather the users' accounts and credentials?

I would recommend that instead of gathering users' emails and passwords manually, you:

1. Build a simple sign up flow in your app according to the [UP Authentication doc](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/authentication).
2. Have your users run that flow
3. Save their OAuth tokens for later use